# F# Seq.head & Seq.tail type mismatch with custom types

Tags: f#, type-mismatch, custom-type

```
type Suit = Spades | Clubs | Hearts | Diamonds
type Rank = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King
type Card = {suit: Suit; rank: Rank}

type Hand = Card seq

let AllSuits = [ Spades; Clubs; Hearts; Diamonds ]
let AllRanks = [ Ace; Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; Eight; Nine; Ten; Jack; Queen; King ]

let cardValue (card:Card) = 
    match card.rank with
    | Ace -> 1
    | Two -> 2
    | Three -> 3
    | Four -> 4
    | Five -> 5
    | Six -> 6
    | Seven -> 7
    | Eight -> 8
    | Nine -> 9
    | Ten | Jack | Queen | King -> 10

let rec handValue (hand:Hand) =
    if Seq.length hand = 1
    then cardValue Seq.head
    else cardValue Seq.head + handValue Seq.tail
```

I have custom types `Rank`, and `Suit`, combined into a custom type `Card`, and a custom type collection `Hand` which is a sequence of cards.

When I use `Seq.head` in the recursive `handValue` function I get the error:

*This expression was expected to have type `'Card'` but here has type `''a -> 'b'`*

I was under the impression that as the `hand` is a sequence of `Card` , that `Seq.head` would return the first element in the sequence, as type `Card`.

Also when I use `Seq.tail` I get the error:

*The type `''a -> seq<'b>'` is not compatible with the type `'Hand'`*

I was under the impression that `Seq.tail` would return a sequence of `Card`, which although not explicitly declared as a `Hand` should be identical in functionality.

**I'm unsure how to approach the first error at all**, and for the second error what would be the most appropriate; casting the `Hand` type to a `Sequence` type and using `Seq.tail`, casting the returned `Sequence` type as a `Hand` type.

Or perhaps there is something minor in the syntax that i'm overlooking completely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `cardValue` the `Seq.head` *function*; you need to apply that function first and pass the result instead:

```
let rec handValue (hand:Hand) =
    if Seq.length hand = 1
    then cardValue (Seq.head hand)
    else cardValue (Seq.head hand) + handValue (Seq.tail hand)
```

N.b. this will fail if passed an empty sequence and isn't tail recursive; fixing these, along with a little redundancy removal, yields something like:

```
let handValue hand =
    let rec impl acc h =
        if Seq.isEmpty h then acc
        else impl (cardValue (Seq.head h) + acc) (Seq.tail h)
    impl 0 hand
```

That said, this is **extremely** inefficient; this code structure would work fine when using a `list` rather than a `seq`, but you're *much* better off using higher-order functions to process the latter:

```
let handValue hand = hand |> Seq.sumBy cardValue
```

Answer (score 4):

### Why Seq.tail is inefficient

ildjarn's answer is correct; I won't repeat what he said, but I'll go into more depth about one detail. He said "this is **extremely** inefficient", but didn't go into details. But I'll tell you why you should **avoid** calling `Seq.tail` repeatedly to iterate through a sequence.

The reason why calling `Seq.tail` repeatedly is extremely inefficient is because of how it's implemented. When you say `let s2 = Seq.tail s1`, it creates a **new** enumerator for `s2` that, when enumerated, will enumerate `s1`, drop its first item, then produce the rest of the items. Then you go through the recursive function again, and do the equivalent of `let s3 = Seq.tail s2`. This creates a new enumerator for `s3` that, when enmerated, will enumerate `s2`, drop its first item, then produce the rest of the items. And when you enumerate `s2`, it enumerates all of `s1`, drops its first item, and produces the rest of the items. The result is that `s3` will drop the first two items of `s1`, but it creates and enumerates **two** enumerators to do so. Then the next time through the loop, `let s4 = Seq.tail s3` produces an enumerator that will enumerate `s3` and drop its first item, which results in enumerating `s2` and dropping its first item, which results in enumerating `s1` and dropping its first item, so you've created and enumerated **three** enumerates in the process.

The result is that calling `Seq.tail` repeatedly on a sequence of length N ends up creating and enumerating 1+2+3+4+5+...+N enumerators, which is O(N^2) in time *and* uses O(N^2) space (!). It's far more efficient to turn the seq into a list; `List.tail` is O(1) in time and uses no space, so enumerating the whole list via `List.tail` is O(N) and uses no extra space besides the O(N) space you used to create the list in the first place.

- Enumerating a seq via `Seq.head` and `Seq.tail`: O(N^2) time and O(N^2) space.
- Enumerating a list via `List.head` and `List.tail`: O(N) time and constant space (if you already had the list) or O(N) space (if you had to create the list from a seq in order to enumerate it).

### The better way

However, there's an even better way to write your `handValue` function. When I look at it, I see that what it's doing is: for every card in the hand, it calculates the value of the card, and sums up all the card values to get the hand value. You know what that sounds like? The [`Seq.sumBy` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.sumby%5B't,%5Eu%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D). So you could rewrite your `handValue` function like this:

```
let handValue (hand:Hand) = hand |> Seq.sumBy cardValue
```

And since `Seq.sumBy` is O(N) and takes zero extra space, that's even more efficient than turning your seq into a list and enumerating through the list.