# F# Need to rewrite code to not require a mutable variable

Tags: f#, boolean, mutable

I have finished the project I have been working on but I am wanting to go back and cleanup my code. In this one instance I used a mutable variable however I want my code to contain no mutable variables. How would I rewrite this code section to return a bool but have it not mutable?

```
let mutable duplicates = false

for el in (combo|>Seq.head) do
    let exists = Seq.exists (fun x -> x = el) (combo|>Seq.item 1)
    duplicates <- exists
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let t = Seq.item 1 combo
let duplicates = Seq.head combo |> Seq.exists (fun el -> Seq.contains el t)
```

[The usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554488/636019) about handling `seq`s in this manner apply.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, works perfectly! The inefficiencies doesn't really matter in my project.

Answer (score 1):

```
let s1 = combo |> Seq.head
let s2 = combo |> Seq.item 1
let duplicates = System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect(s1, s2) |> Seq.isEmpty |> not
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works but I went with the other response as it was simpler to me and didn't require using Linq.